# using webap2 EF, return stored procedure that includes pivot failing

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, pivot

I have a stored procedure saved on my db that uses pivot table functionality.
So based on the client I am looking at, they can have 1 column of PACCT, or multiple columns of PACCT.  If you look at the last 2 columns of the result picture, this shows an example of 2 columns of accounts... and each column is titled by PACCT value. (as it should)

I am trying to return this in EF webapi2.  Since the columns keep changing I can't model this correct?  How can I return this query result using webapi.  The error message I am getting is 
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

this is how I am trying it run it...

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<object>("dbo.CompareStrategy @cid, @targetDate", new SqlParameter("cid", cid), new SqlParameter("targetDate", targetDate));
```

[image]

Comment: What would you do with the result if you got it?

Comment: retrieve it from my web client front end..        [Route("api/user/CompareStrategy/")]
        [HttpGet]
        public object CompareStrategy(int cid, string targetDate)
        {

Comment: If you are just going to use the data to generate JSON, why do a dynamic pivot it on the server.  Just return a proper group by result with a fixed shape.  Or let SQL Server create the JSON directly.

Comment: because every time the sp gets called the number of columns gets bigger or smaller

Comment: Right.  Stop doing that.  Have the stored procedure return the same number of columns every time.

Comment: guess thats what I'm confused on, when client 1 calls it he has 3 columns of data... when client 2 calls it he has 10 columns of data.  its based on how many accounts the client has